# azure functions queue trigger configurations

Tags: azure-functions, azure-queues

I am trying to find the right place to set a batch size for my queue trigger. Basically all these properties..
"batchSize": 1,
"maxDequeueCount": 2,
"maxPollingInterval": 5000,

When I checked this article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

It does not talk about setting up configurations for queue triggers in host.json.

I have the following trigger which I only need fired one at a time, so batch size 1.

The name of the queue is saved in my local.settings.json in variable called "DispatchQueueName"

```
public static void OnFieldDevicePollingRequest_Run([QueueTrigger("%DispatchQueueName%", Connection = "AVStorageAccessKey")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Start Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
```

I am using .net core and need help with this soon please.

Comment: The host.json metadata file contains global configuration options that affect all functions for a function app.Other function app configuration options are managed in your app settings.

Answer (score 3):

> It does not talk about setting up configurations for queue triggers in host.json.

You could set below configuration in host.json.

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "queues": {
            "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
            "batchSize": 1,
            "maxDequeueCount": 2
        }
    }
}
```

The output is as below:

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#hostjson-settings).

Comment: Thank you so very much @Joey, I have two another question.. 1) How can I specify the name of the queue in extensions. What if I have two functions monitoring two different queues and I want different specs for each?

Comment: 1) Queue names are [configured at the function level,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---attributes) in attributes (.NET) or function.json (everything else.) 2) Polling/batch/retry configuration is managed at the function app level, so you would need to move your queue triggered functions into separate function apps to configure different values.

Comment: As the comment I post before, the host.json metadata file contains global configuration options that affect all functions for a function app. So you could not specify for different queues.

Comment: I think the description of settings got moved here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=csharp#host-json.